# iOS App Store Submission Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an iOS app that works fine when I deploy to an iPhone but throws the following error when attempting to submit to the App Store via Xcode.

How would I go about unblocking this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

> Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at 'Payload/Picsolve.app/GooglePlus.bundle' does not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

I have checked what the error suggests... and it looks like the CFBundleExecutable key does not exist and the CFBundlePackageType of BNDL already exists.

[image]

I removed the Executable File item, and then did a project clean followed by Archive. I then attempted to validate the new archive for app store submission and the same error message displayed.

Comment: OK, so it turns out the GPP Sign in package is pretty deprecated, and will not work against ios 8 +

Comment: I managed to get it fixed by removing the reference to this package all together.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem today with the same exact error message when trying to submit our app (using Xcode 7 beta 5) but instead of the `instabug.bundle` bit, it was for me `TencentOpenApi_IOS_Bundle.bundle`.

I solved the problem by finding the named bundle in the project then - just as the error message suggests - edited the `Info.plist` that is in the bundle by removing the `CFBundleExecutable` key. The `CFBundlePackageType` key was already set to `BNDL` so I didn't touch it.

After these changes, I did Product > Clean and then had no problem submitting the app to the App store.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, It does really help :), in the end for my scenario i removed the bundle all together because we did not use it anymore in the codebase.